# Popen('python') in VS Code crashes the debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Running the following code from the teminal works fine:

```py
import subprocess
print 'hello'
subprocess.Popen('python')
```

Running it from VS Code (using 'Current file' debug configuration) crashes the process with:

```
E-0000.090: Exception escaped from start_client

            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/home/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.49689/pythonFiles/lib/python/old_ptvsd/ptvsd/log.py", line 110, in g
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
              ...
              File "/home/me/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.49689/pythonFiles/lib/python/old_ptvsd/ptvsd/daemon.py", line 145, in start
                raise RuntimeError('already started')
            RuntimeError: already started
```

Is there a setting to prevent the debugger from trying to connect to the subprocess?